# Is there a way to parametrize the configuration space of all convex polyhedra of a given combinatorial type as a convex set?

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra, configuration-spaces

I'm sure this is easy/known, but I'm not hitting an appropriate search term for finding the answer and the coffee hasn't kicked in enough to come up with it myself:

Let $T$ be a simplicial 2-complex homeomorphic to the sphere with $n$ vertices. $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$ gives us a configuration space for $T$ of all possible realizations of $T$ as a polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Take $C\subset \mathbb{R}^{3n}$ to be the configuration space of all realizations of $T$ as a convex polyhedron.

We might ask, is $C$ a convex set? Which is akin to asking if we have two realizations $P_0\in C$ and $P_1\in C$, both convex, and we linearly interpolate between the two in $R^{3n}$, giving us a continuous family of polyhedra $P_t$ for $t\in[0,1]$, is $P_t\in C$ for all $t\in[0,1]$? It seems to me that the answer here is no, because we can do something like simply rotate $P_0$ around some axis through the point at the average of its vertices by $\pi$ and then do this interpolation and it seems like the polyhedron will admit of some self-intersections at intermediate values of $t$ for lots of examples (though my intuition may be off here, I haven't actually constructed an example where this happens).

If I'm wrong about my intuition above, then I'm interested in why, and if I'm right, then I'm further interested in the following questions.

**Question 1:** What if we select a face $i_0j_0k_0$ of the polyhedron $P_0$ and require that in $P_1$, vertex $i_1 = i_0$ (so that $i_t$ is constant in $P_t$), $j_1$ lies on the ray $i_0 j_0$ (so that the segment $i_t j_t$ is just stretching in $P_t$ with one side fixed), and $k_1$ lies in the plane supporting $i_0 j_0 k_0$ such that the orientation of triangle $i_1 j_1 k_1$ is the same as $i_0 j_0 k_0$ (this way the triangle $i_t j_t k_t$ remains coplanar throughout the motion and doesn't flip orientation). Let $C_{i_0j_0k_0}\subset C$ be the configuration space with these additional requirements. It *feels* like $C_{i_0j_0k_0}$ is convex. Is it? Does this appear anywhere in the literature? **Update:** The answer here is no. I can construct examples.

**Question 2:** if the answer to question 1 is still no, it (again) *feels* like there *ought* to be a way to interpolate between two convex polyhedra with the same combinatorics in such a way that all intermediate polyhedra are convex. If there is, is there a different way of parametrizing the polyhedra such that the appropriately defined configuration space *is* convex, meaning we can interpolate linearly the parameters between two realizations while all intermediate polyhedra are also convex realizations?

Comment: I forgot to add question 3: If question 2 is a yes, what if we add an additional constraint: each edge $e$ has a given range of lengths $[e_{min}, e_{max}]$ that it is allowed to take on. Is the corresponding configuration space convex?

Comment: Coffee starting to kick in a little -- for question 2, I'm thinking you could do an interpolation on the intrinsic metric and then apply Alexandrov's theorem. But somehow you have to guarantee you maintain the total angle deficit.

Comment: Answer to question 1: not necessarily. I can construct an example (in fact I constructed an example polygon where this idea breaks convexity and this can easily be extended to an example of polyhedra where this occurs).

Comment: I would guess the answer is "no", based on the universality of realization spaces of 4-dimensional polytopes.  If you haven't read J\"{u}rgen Richter-Gebert's monograph "Realization Spaces of Polytopes" from the mid 1990's, then you should.  (You can probably find it on the internet.)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a move towards an answer to questions 2 and 3.

First, a remark about triangles parametrized by their edge lengths—the configuration space of a single triangle parametrized by its edge lengths $x$, $y$, and $z$ is given by the intersection of three half-planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $x + y < z$, $x + z < y$, and $y + z < x$. This means that given two triangles $T_1$ and $T_2$, we can linearly interpolate between them by linearly interpolating their edge lengths.

Now, if $P_1$ and $P_2$ are two polyhedra with the same combinatorics, we can interpolate between their polyhedral metrics by a linear interpolation of their edge lengths. It’s currently unclear to me if $P_1$ and $P_2$ being convex metrics is sufficient to guarantee that the interpolation stays convex at all points between the two. But it does seem clear that the total discrete curvature is conserved by this interpolation. So assuming that the polyhedral metric $(1-t)P_1 + t P_2$ is convex, by Alexandrov’s theorem, there is a unique convex polyhedron realizing the metric. The problems with this are (a) I haven’t shown here that $(1-t)P_1 + t P_2$ is convex (indeed, I’m not sure if it is), and (b) Alexandrov’s theorem doesn’t necessarily give you back the same combinatorics, so it may be that for intermediate values of $t\in(0,1)$, edge flips have to occur.

Any ideas on (a) or (b)? I assume this is well known, but I do not know it…